# SSL certificate for sql-server on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql-server, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an ec2 node provisioned to host mssql server. I'm trying to request and install an ssl certificate for this node so I can securely connect to it but I can't get the certificate to appear in the MSSQL configuration utility drop down. From my research, this is because the certificate is 'invalid' according to sql server, even though it is valid according to the certificate snap-in.

I suspect it might have something to do with the CN name - but I'm not sure.

What are the correct request parameters to get a valid certificate for sql server? I'm using startSSL.

**Important attributes:**

```
ServerName:  FOO123
Domain:      WORKGROUP
DNS Suffix:  mydomain.com
DNS alias:   db.mydomain.com
```